# How to save value entered in custom field in the Source (MSI) form?

Tags: adminhtml, magento2.4, forms, adminform

In a Magento 2.4.5, I've (successfully) added a custom field (opening_mon) to the AdminHtml form for a Source (MSI), using view/adminhtml/ui_component/inventory_source_form.xml. I do see the field in the form.

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="opening_times" sortOrder="40">
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">Opening times</label>
            <collapsible>true</collapsible>
            <opened>false</opened>
            <dataScope>general</dataScope>
        </settings>
        <field name="opening_mon" formElement="input" sortOrder="50">
            <settings>
                <dataScope>extension_attributes.opening_mon</dataScope>
                <dataType>string</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Opening times Monday</label>
            </settings>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I've also added a field in the database table inventory_source (using etc/db_schema.xml). I see the field in the database table.

```
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="inventory_source">
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="opening_mon" length="50" nullable="true" comment="opening times monday" />
    </table>
</schema>
```

When I enter a value in the custom field and save the form, I get confirmation the form is saved ('The Source has been saved.') but I don't see the value in the database table (inventory_source). My expectation is that I would see this value in the database table.
How to save value entered in custom field in the Source (MSI) form? I've tried many suggestions from internet.
Also I need to know how to show the value from the database field opening_mon in the form field.

A working example for M2.4 is highly appreciated or documentation I can use.
Thanks in advance.
Kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you try to modify specific logic and you need to made additional changes

**1. Register your field in extension attributes**

`app/code/Acme/StackExchange/etc/extension_attributes.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\InventoryApi\Api\Data\SourceInterface">
        <attribute code="opening_mon" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

**2. Register Source Repository Plugin**

`app/code/Acme/StackExchange/etc/di.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\InventoryApi\Api\SourceRepositoryInterface">
        <plugin name="Acme_StackExchange_Plugin_InventoryApi_Api_SourceRepositoryPlugin"
                type="Acme\StackExchange\Plugin\InventoryApi\Api\SourceRepositoryPlugin"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**3. Create Source Repository Plugin**

`app/code/Acme/StackExchange/Plugin/InventoryApi/Api/SourceRepositoryPlugin.php`

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Acme\StackExchange\Plugin\InventoryApi\Api;

use Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesFactory;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\InventoryApi\Api\Data\SourceInterface;
use Magento\InventoryApi\Api\Data\SourceSearchResultsInterface;
use Magento\InventoryApi\Api\SourceRepositoryInterface;

class SourceRepositoryPlugin
{
    protected const ATTRIBUTE = 'opening_mon';

    protected ExtensionAttributesFactory $extensionAttributesFactory;

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function __construct(
        ExtensionAttributesFactory $extensionAttributesFactory
    ) {
        $this->extensionAttributesFactory = $extensionAttributesFactory;
    }


    public function beforeSave(
        SourceRepositoryInterface $subject,
        SourceInterface $source
    ): array {
        if ($source instanceof DataObject) {
            $extensionAttributes = $source->getExtensionAttributes();
            if ($extensionAttributes !== null) {
                $source->setData(self::ATTRIBUTE, $extensionAttributes->getOpeningMon());
            }
        }

        return [$source];
    }

    private function extendSource(SourceInterface $source): void
    {
        if (!$source instanceof DataObject) {
            return;
        }

        $extensionAttributes = $source->getExtensionAttributes();

        if ($extensionAttributes === null) {
            $extensionAttributes = $this->extensionAttributesFactory->create(SourceInterface::class);
            /** @noinspection PhpParamsInspection */
            $source->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);
        }

        $extensionAttributes->setOpeningMon($source->getData(self::ATTRIBUTE));
    }

    public function afterGet(
        SourceRepositoryInterface $subject,
        SourceInterface $source
    ): SourceInterface {
        $this->extendSource($source);

        return $source;
    }

    public function afterGetList(
        SourceRepositoryInterface $subject,
        SourceSearchResultsInterface $sourceSearchResults
    ): SourceSearchResultsInterface {
        $items = $sourceSearchResults->getItems();
        array_walk(
            $items,
            [$this, 'extendSource']
        );

        return $sourceSearchResults;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Victor,

Don't know how you did it and it worked!!! Incredible! 
Thank you so much. I've been breaking my head over this issue for so many hours.